# Symfony2 : Display fetch join result in twig

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I simply want to list all entities in a view from a table (building) which needs a join to display some details (building management). I want to use Doctrine [fetch join](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) option to avoid extra queries because every buildings must display its data from its building management.

Below is a basic controller example. My problem is that it is mandatory to include `bm` in the select in order to use fetch and not regular join. Therefore, the `$entities` variable contains `b` and `bm` entities and the loop in Twig is only waiting for `b` entities. How can I solve that?

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // This way is working, but extra queries are generated when I need to access the BuildingManagement data from Building entity
    //$entities = $em->getRepository('TrilogisPropertyBundle:Building')->findAll();

    $entities = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT b, bm
             FROM MyBundle:Building b
             JOIN MyBundle:BuildingManagement bm WITH bm.building = b.id
             ORDER BY b.id')                                   
            ->getResult();

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Test:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    ));
}
```

And in TWIG

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Building Management</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ entity.id }}</td>     
            <td>{{ entity.buildingManagement.id}}</td> <-- will crash because the entity must be a building and not a buildingManagement                                            
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have any ORM Relation between Building and BuildingManagement ? This way, you would be able to access BuildingManagement from the Building entit

Comment: @Cr3aHal0 Of course I have a relation. But you need to be aware that accessing BuildingManagement from Building will create an extra queries I want to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you said about having relations between those two in comment holds true then you're probably doing `JOIN` the wrong way:

Query should probably be:

```
$entities = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT b, bm
             FROM MyBundle:Building b
             JOIN b.buildingManagement bm
             ORDER BY b.id')                                   
            ->getResult();
```

Some things to note:

- You will need a `buildingManagement` member in your `Building` entity in order for this to work.
- `buildingManagement` should be, from the look of it, annotated with `@ManyToOne`. Could be `@ManyToMany` but that depends on app's logic.
- Optionally, `buildingManagement` should be marked as inversed. We could help you determine that if you update your question with entities (both).

Comment: Thank you, the fact to specify the bundle of the joined table force to not hydrate the building object and returns buildingManagement as rows.